# Can a WCF Service hosted in Windows service accessed by multiple clients?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-services

I am very new to WCF and would like to ask this question.
My idea is to host the WCF Service in Windows service. Once I am done with this can I make this service available to multiple clients in the same network? If so how? Which binding am I supposed to use?

Answer (score 10):

> can I make this service available to multiple clients in the same
>   network?

Yes, that is the point.

> If so how?

Create a client and connect to it. Trillions of samples around. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx) is one of many.

> Which binding am I supposed to use?

Any binding you want. But in this case I would use `netTcpBinding`.

Answer (score 6):

I've always found this [flow chart](http://mohammedatef.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/select-wcf-binding-2/) helpful for binding selection.

[image: WCF Binding Selection Flow Chart].

Answer (score 0):

Answer is yes, WCF service will be available for all the clients in the network. If you concerned about processing several requests at the same time, it's possible, too. WCF do this for you. Read [ServiceBehaviorAttribute.InstanceContextMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode.aspx) description.